# Show that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{2 \pi i \nu u}}{u^s} du =\Gamma(1-s) (\frac{2 \pi \nu}{i} )^{s-1}$

Tags: integration, proof-explanation, gamma-function

In Theorem 4.13. in Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function* the following equality is assumed without proof: $$\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{2 \pi i \nu u}}{u^s}  du = \Gamma(1-s) \bigg(\dfrac{2 \pi \nu}{i} \bigg)^{s-1}.$$ How is this derived?

Writing the integral definition of $\Gamma(1-s)$ I couldn't reach from RHS to LHS. Neither by change of variable nor by $\Gamma(s) e^{\frac{i \pi s}{2}} = \int_0^{\infty} y^{s-1} e^{iy} dy$ (Rademacher's book), from LHS to RHS  is also not achievable.

Comment: Take $s=1-s$ and $y=2\pi \nu u$ in the formula by Rademacher.

Comment: There is a thing about the formula by Rademacher: it is valid for $<0\sigma<1$ so the change of s is not valid I belive.

Comment: There is a thing about the formula by Rademacher: it is valid for $<0\sigma<1$ so the change of s is not valid I belive.

Comment: Well, assume that $1-s$ satisfies the condition on $s$ in Rademacher's formula. Note that the two $s$ are not the same $s$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the path of integration to the upper vertical axis. To do this consider the contour going from $\epsilon$ to $R$ then from $R$ to $iR$ around the arc in the positive direction, then from $iR$ to $i\epsilon$ and from there around the arc to $\epsilon$ in the negative direction. By Chauchy's theorem the integral around this contour is zero. I think you can take it from here :)

Comment: In the arc from R to iR, the integral does not vanish: $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{e^{2 \pi \nu R e^{i \theta}}}{(R e^{i \theta})^s} i R e^{i \theta} d \theta$ for $0<Re(s)<1$ which is the domain in the theorem. ($\nu$ is positive integer).

Comment: @Ali you forgot an $i$ in the exponent.

Comment: I considered exponent without i bc of its appearance on imaginary axis and not appearance of it on real line but I made a mistake since the original integral has i on for the real axis

Answer (score 0):

When $\Re(\alpha)>0$ is fixed and $\beta>0$, a change of variable gives

$$
\int_0^{+\infty}u^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta u}\mathrm du=\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{-\alpha}.
$$

Observe that the integral on the left hand side converges uniformly in any compact subset of $\Re(\beta)>0$ and any compact subset of $i\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, and the term on the right hand side is a one-valued analytic function in $A=\{\beta\in\mathbb C:\Re(\beta)\ge0\}\setminus\{0\}$, we conclude that this identity is valid in $A$ via analytic continuation.

Now, set $\alpha=1-s$ and $\beta=-2\pi\nu i$ so that we arrive at the following:

$$
\int_0^{+\infty}u^{-s}e^{2\pi i\nu u}\mathrm du=\Gamma(1-s)\left(2\pi\nu\over i\right)^{s-1}.
$$

Comment: How do you get the formula in $A$ and not only $\Re\beta>0$? "that the integral on the left hand side converges uniformly in any compact subset of $\Re(\beta)>0$ and any compact subset of $i\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$" is not an argument.

Comment: And it's not true for the ranges considered in your answer.

Comment: And if the ranges are correct you should to say why you can take the limit or what theorem you are resorting to.

Comment: Indeed, the formula is initially proved to be valid in $\Re(\beta)>0$. Subsequently, it can be proved that for any closed interval $I$ not containing zero, the integral converges uniformly whenever $\beta=iy$ and $y\in I$.

Comment: As a result, the integral is holomorphic in the region $\{\beta\in\mathbb C:\Re(\beta)>0\}\cup i\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}=A$. Because the formula on the right hand side (taking principal branch, of course) is also analytic in $A$, we can use the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) to conclude that they are the same.

Comment: I pointed out a mistake and you insist that there is no mistake :<